# Usage pronominal => inversion de modalité

Tags: verbes-pronominaux, modalité

On connaît le cas de *douter* (ne pas être sûr) / ***se*** douter (avoir de fortes présomptions)
On peut ajouter *imaginer* (se figurer) / ***s***'imaginer (croire à tort) (*1)

Connaissez-vous d'autres verbes dont la modalité s'**inverse** avec l'usage pronominal. (*2)

(*1) oui, *s'imaginer* peut aujourd'hui prendre un autre sens mais c'est au sens de *croire à tort* qu'il est apparu dans la langue.

(*2) s'inverser et non prendre un tout autre sens.

Des suggestions en d'autres langues que le français sont également bienvenues.

Comment: Je crois pouvoir être d'accord pour le  premier exemple, mais pour le second l'incertitude me force à recourir au TLFi, lequel donne quelque chose de contradictoire: B. S'imaginer qqc. Se figurer, croire à tort. Il n'y aurait pas de différence; « imaginer » ne semble pas signifier « se figurer ».

Comment: @user168676 : Tu as raison relativement à ta source. J'ai repris la source DHLF pour faire référence au sens premier des verbes. Celui qui a été conféré lors de leur apparition. Et oui, le sens a évolué depuis.

Comment: @aCOSwtWhat about "intéresser/s'intéresser"?

Comment: @user168676 : Je ne sens pas vraiment d'**in**intérêt dans le pronominal, si ?

Comment: @aCOSwtI see, it's strictly on the domain of the sense itself, there is no question of inversion between subject and predicate. Beside the point then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ambitionnant peut-être un peu :

- **Appeler** → Lancer le nom de qqn pour prendre contact. C’est un acte concret, sonore, mais qui ne dure que le temps que s’établisse le contact.
- **S’appeler** → Porter un nom auquel on répond. L’attribution est généralement continue, s’étendant dans le temps sans être forcément permanente, mais l’usage qui en est fait est la plupart du temps en un état strictement potentiel et latent, silencieux.
- **Barrer / Se barrer** → En barrant le chemin, on peut empêcher quelqu’un de se barrer.

Comment: NonPaduTOUT! Oh...wait... ! Clever en fait que c'est comme suggestion. Si elle ne répond pas aux critères fixés dans l'OP, cette suggestion me fait réaliser que l'inversion de sens peut très bien ne concerner qu'un des axes. Ici, en l'occurrence, la durée. J'accepte donc sans détour et avec **gratitude**. (Nota, mais c'est très secondaire, les niveaux de *concrétude* relative de deux mots sont toujours... plus ou moins... hasardeux)

Comment: @aCOSwt La concrétude demeure abstraite, c'est bien vrai. Qu'on me permette donc de spécifier un peu et d'ajouter à l'axe de la durée celui du bruit, sur lequel il est plus facile de mettre le doigt (ou le tympan, c'est selon).

Comment: Merci à vous de continuer à vous préoccuper de cette question. Je ne crois pas pouvoir retenir votre dernière suggestion (barrer) car il me semble qu'ici, l'inversion de sens repose plus sur le locatif (explicite ou non) que sur la forme pronominale. *Je barre ici / je me barre **d** 'ici.*

Comment: @aCOSwt Ah bon? Je croyais que l’entravement du mouvement de l’un pouvait s’opposer à l’indiscutable mouvement de l’autre. Peut-être seulement que l’exemple était mal choisi?

Comment: Oui alors sans parler de mouvement en entendant *barrer* au sens compétition. Ça a le mérite de virer le locatif. X est barré par Y au sens où les performances / qualités de Y sont tellement supérieures à celles de X que, tant que Y sera là,  X ne peut prétendre qu'à des accessits. Et auquel cas si Y se barre, il ne barre plus Y. Cela se conçoit. Il a en tout cas un truc que, au contraire de *douter* n'avaient ni *imaginer* ni *appeler* et très révélateur d'une inversion quelque part : Y ne peut pas à la fois barrer et se barrer. Merci!

Answer (score 1):

Au Québec, peut-être aussi ailleurs je ne sais pas, le terme **s’énerver** possède une acception qui se définirait à peu près ainsi :

> S’amuser bruyamment en courant à gauche et à droite.

On pourrait donc penser à des enfants qui ont passé l’après-midi à **s’énerver** pour leur plus grand plaisir, et à **énerver** les voisins pour leur plus grand déplaisir.